# javascript errors on mobile browser, not on desktop

Tags: javascript, mobile, bug

I'm building an application based on the wordpress backend.

The app is working correctly on desktop, but on my ipad I noticed the javascript broke. I made some investigations and I discovered that the problem was both on chrome and safari in either ipad or iphone.

I used the service http://transmog.net/iphone-simulator/ to simulate a galaxy S3 and problem persisted.

Transmorg allows me to see the javascript console and i found a couple of errors, one in the dashboardo and one in a custom post manage page.

In the dashboard I found:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Text> has no method 'getElementsByTagName' jslib:412
```

And in the other page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined load-scripts.php=3fc=3d1=26load=255B=255D=3dhoverIntent,common,admin-bar,he…p-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,postbox,post,thickbox=26ver=3d3.6:36
postboxes._pb_edit load-scripts.php=3fc=3d1=26load=255B=255D=3dhoverIntent,common,admin-bar,he…p-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,postbox,post,thickbox=26ver=3d3.6:36
postboxes._pb_change load-scripts.php=3fc=3d1=26load=255B=255D=3dhoverIntent,common,admin-bar,he…p-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,postbox,post,thickbox=26ver=3d3.6:36
postboxes.init load-scripts.php=3fc=3d1=26load=255B=255D=3dhoverIntent,common,admin-bar,he…p-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,postbox,post,thickbox=26ver=3d3.6:36
postboxes.add_postbox_toggles load-scripts.php=3fc=3d1=26load=255B=255D=3dhoverIntent,common,admin-bar,he…p-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,postbox,post,thickbox=26ver=3d3.6:36
(anonymous function) load-scripts.php=3fc=3d1=26load=255B=255D=3dhoverIntent,common,admin-bar,he…p-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,postbox,post,thickbox=26ver=3d3.6:37
c load-scripts.php=3fc=3d1=26load=255B=255D=3djquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils=26ver=3d3.6:4
p.fireWith load-scripts.php=3fc=3d1=26load=255B=255D=3djquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils=26ver=3d3.6:4
x.extend.ready load-scripts.php=3fc=3d1=26load=255B=255D=3djquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils=26ver=3d3.6:4
q load-scripts.php=3fc=3d1=26load=255B=255D=3djquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils=26ver=3d3.6:4
```

(sorry for the poor formatting)

Should I suppose is a wordpress error or its somehow my fault, even if I don't believe so, since I havent touched the files written above.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you just check it whether these errors persist or not by deactivating all plugins and changing theme to default theme like twentythirteen ?

Comment: uhm... is a production site and my collegues are using it to do their job right now. I usually do tests on local, but I don't know how to simulate a mobile environment then. I'll try. Hwr the number of plugins installed it's really minimal: Easy Theme and Plugin Upgrades, Filters, ManageWP - Worker, Members, Pods, WordPress Twitter Bootstrap CSS, WPide.